# Postgresql streaming replication - choose databases to sync

Tags: postgresql

I have been reading on the Postgresql replication streaming (as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/hot-standby.html)) and was wondering if it is possible to choose which databases are synced, or if it has to be the entire DB server.  E.g. if I have database1, database2, and database3 in my master server, can I have my slave server sync only database1 and database2?  And further, could I have a second slave server sync a different subset of databases, like only database3?

I am using postgresql version 9.6.

Comment: No, not possible. Streaming replication always replicates the whole cluster

Answer (score 1):

No, traditional streaming replication cannot do that.

To replicate per database, you would have to use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) instead.  But this is not available until v10.  (Certain pieces of it were available back to 9.4, but using it required some very deep expertise until v10 when a user-friendly front-end was added)